# How is the biggest animal ever existed measured?

Tags: dinosaurs

Blue whales are considered the biggest animal ever lived with maximum confirmed length nearing 30 meters. While some titanosaurs reportedly were somewhat longer (up to 40 meters for Argentinosaurus and up to 37 meters for Patagotitan).

It's obvious that size constitutes not just length, but I don't quite understand how one can be certain that the said sauropods were smaller provided that they are about <s>1.5</s> ~1.33 times longer?

Comment: Just look at the body structure of a blue whale vs a sauropod. Whales are round/elliptical in cross-section, and their width is larger proportional to their length than sauropods. Put simply, they just have more volume, even though they may be somewhat shorter. BTW, 40:30 is not 1.5x.

Comment: @MattDMo you are right, but I believe there should be more precise way to say that than just raw approximation based on the body structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd also be forgetting about the largest animal ever recorded which is a [syphonophore at 46 meters](https://earthsky.org/earth/longest-ocean-animal-ever-recorded/), a spagetti jellyfish.

A blue whale can weigh 196 tons. Argentinosaurus could weigh in at 77 tons:

*Initial estimates placed it at 40 meters (131 feet) long with a weight of 77 tons. This makes it comparable to the next largest titanosaur, Puertasaurus (which has been estimated at 73-83 tons by some studies), and thus one of the largest land animals in Earth's history.*

People can confuse voluminous, massive, largest, and longest. Scientists will generally not agree about the best way to measure he largest animal, whether it is the syphonophore or the whale.